# Linux Mint Wireless doesn't connect

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint

I've installed Linux mint debian edition (LMDE), and following this tutorial > http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/161 I did installed the network driver.

The available connections appears to me, but when i try to connect to my connection at first time, I got this message:

> (4) Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

And the following tries, I got this another message:

> (32) Insufficient privileges.

EDIT:
The last piece of the logs:

```
Oct  5 00:22:38 gsouza-host ntpd[2116]: peers refreshed
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host NetworkManager[2019]: <info> (wlan0): bringing up device.
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host wpa_supplicant[2055]: nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host wpa_supplicant[2055]: Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host wpa_supplicant[2055]: rfkill: WLAN soft blocked
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host NetworkManager[2019]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host NetworkManager[2019]: <info> WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host NetworkManager[2019]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host NetworkManager[2019]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host NetworkManager[2019]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host NetworkManager[2019]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Oct  5 00:22:42 gsouza-host wpa_supplicant[2055]: rfkill: WLAN unblocked
Oct  5 00:22:44 gsouza-host avahi-daemon[1827]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::7ae4:ff:fe4a:13a9.
Oct  5 00:22:44 gsouza-host avahi-daemon[1827]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct  5 00:22:44 gsouza-host avahi-daemon[1827]: Registering new address record for fe80::7ae4:ff:fe4a:13a9 on wlan0.*.
Oct  5 00:22:46 gsouza-host ntpd[2116]: Listen normally on 7 wlan0 fe80::7ae4:ff:fe4a:13a9 UDP 123
Oct  5 00:22:46 gsouza-host ntpd[2116]: peers refreshed
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

create missing file:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla
```

put this in it:

```
[nm-applet]
Identity=unix-group:netdev
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

You aka USER should be member of the group `netdev`